# Chrome throws CORS error when calling https from http, and ASP Core does not send CORS header

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

Is request considered a CORS even if it is between addresses in the same domain but with a different protocol?

Because I get code 401 in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
https://xxx.yyy.com/appname/css/left-pane-menu.component.min.css. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://xxx.yyy.com' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

On one hand, the asp core will not send cors headers for the same origin, on the other Chrome will not accept request from other protocol. Wow.

What are my options besides calling resources from the same protocol.
I can't do that. I need to call https always due to some Azure Enterprise proxy setting that mislead my site into thinking it is called with http when it was called with https thus the base url tag in html was set to http://xxx.yyy.com/myapp and Chrome would throw that it cannot access insecure resources from secure connection.

My Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddCors(); 
      services.AddMvc()
              .AddJsonOptions(x =>
              {
                    x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                });
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
            app.UseCors(c=>
                c
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
            );

        app.UseResponseCompression();

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions());

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
}
```

Comment: That's the correct behavior. Http/https are classified as different origins. You will have to handle that in your applictation that both http and https are allowed

Comment: But your Cors is also configured wrong. You should put CORS after your static files middleware (or limit it only to js/json),  because then even css will be checked via CORS, which you most likely don't want to do. Also post your CORS setup code

Comment: What are you using for authorisation?

Comment: @Tseng What do you mean "will be checked via CORS? I need to load css via ajax call (webpack/angular 2)

Comment: As there's no sign of authorisation in your startup snippet, are you using Windows Authentication?

Comment: Yes I do but this is not the case here.

Comment: @Tseng of course I need cors on .css files because they are loaded from https endpoint while the main html is at http endpoint and the css is loaded by javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to setup your CORS to something like that, because `https://xxx.yyy.com` and `http://xxx.yyy.com` are treated as different origins.

The reason behind that is, different port are also classified as different origins and http runs on port 80 and https on 443.

Some browsers do treat this differently, i.e. Internet Explorer did (or it used to, not sure if its still true for the new versions) treat different ports as same original, Firefox and Chrome don't (which is correct behavior according to the specs).

```
options.AddPolicy("YYYOrigin", policyBuilder =>
{
    policyBuilder
         // you need to specify both
        .WithOrigins("https://xxx.yyy.com", "http://xxx.yyy.com")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
});

app.UseCors("YYYOrigin");
```

Comment: But what if I have .AllowAnyOrigin() ?

Comment: `.AllowAnyOrigin()` should always work, unless your code throws an exception, because the exception middleware clears all headers, including CORS headers. If the loaded files are part of an AngularJS application (typically you don't download css files via AJAX), then put the `UseCors("...")` before your static middleware. Otherwise after it, if you only want to protect your controllers/actions

Comment: You need to register your static middleware before authorization, otherwise your app can't load for unauthorized users (first time visitors)